# Asterisk tries to delete ubuntu-desktop when installing

Tags: apt, asterisk

I'm trying to install **asterisk-15.4.0** with

```
roman@romanPC:~/asterisk-install/asterisk-15.4.0$ sudo ./contrib/scripts/install_prereq install
```

At some point it says:

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

  Remove the following packages:                                 
1)      apturl                                                       
2)      hwdata                                                       
3)      libcurl4-gnutls-dev                                          
4)      nautilus-share                                               
5)      nvidia-prime                                                 
6)      pciutils                                                     
7)      software-properties-gtk                                      
8)      ubuntu-desktop                                               
9)      ubuntu-drivers-common                                        
10)     ubuntu-standard
```

and

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apturl{a} bbswitch-dkms{u} hwdata{a} libcurl4-gnutls-dev{a} nautilus-share{a} nvidia-prime{a} 
  pciutils{a} software-properties-gtk{a} ubuntu-desktop{a} ubuntu-drivers-common{a} 
  ubuntu-standard{a}
```

and further

```
Removing hwdata (0.267-1) ...
Removing libcurl4-gnutls-dev:amd64 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.7) ...
Removing ubuntu-standard (1.361.1) ...
Removing ubuntu-desktop (1.361.1) ...
Removing software-properties-gtk (0.96.20.7) ...
Removing ubuntu-drivers-common (1:0.4.17.7) ...
Removing pciutils (1:3.3.1-1.1ubuntu1.1) ...
```

Is that OK? Why does it have to delete such packets as ubuntu-desktop? Should I be worried? Should I fix this or leave it alone?

My OS: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

It also said (I don't know, maybe that helps):

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.13.0-36 linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic linux-headers-4.13.0-37
  linux-headers-4.13.0-37-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-119 linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic
  linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic linux-image-4.13.0-37-generic linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-37-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic
```

Here is the [whole log](https://pastebin.com/s9azVquU). Thanks.

Comment: ubuntu-desktop is a package that installs the Ubuntu Desktop Environment (GNOME in 17.10 and newer, Unity in 17.04 and older), it's recommended to not remove it, as it can make the DE, and so on "Not Required" and therefore be added to the removal list for 'sudo apt autoremove'.

Comment: Also, 'software-properties-common' should definitely not be removed, unless you are deliberately trying to remove the command for adding a PPA to your system, or have an alternative PPA manager installed (e.g: mintsources).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just happened to me last night, it seems like the best way to prevent this is to run
`apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` BEFORE running the install_prereq script.

In my case I think it removed my network manager, because attempts to re-install removed packages gave me errors.  It may be possible to re-install from the apt-get cache, but I will be using my original install CD to repair.

Similar issues have been logged:
[contrib/scripts/install_prereq can remove ssh daemon on ubuntu](https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/ASTERISK-26244)
[network-manager uninstalled on ubuntu desktop 14.04](https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/ASTERISK-25977)